# How to remove drawable image from edittext through code in android

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have placed an image in edit text by the following code

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/searchfilter"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:hint="Enter search keyword"
    android:drawableRight="@drawable/ic_launcher"/>
```

I need to hide this image through java code

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try the folloing code

```
editText.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0,0,0,0);
```

Answer (score 6):

With this you can remove the `drawable` at the any side of your `EditText`

```
editText.setCompoundDrawables(null, null, null, null);
```

Answer (score 2):

Try with `setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds()` method as follows...

```
editText.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, 0, 0, 0);
```